# Suppose $H|U : U \to Y$ and $H|V : V \to Y$ are continuous. Prove that $H : U \cup V \to Y$ is also continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am reading a topology book by Yukio Matsumoto.
There is the following problem in this book:

> Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces.
> Let $U$, $V$ be open sets in $X$.
> Consider $U$, $V$, $U \cup V$ as subspaces of $X$.
> Let $H$ be a mapping from $U \cup V$ to $Y$.
> Suppose $H|U : U \to Y$ and $H|V : V \to Y$ are continuous.
> Prove that $H : U \cup V \to Y$ is also continuous.

My solution is here:

> Let $O \subset Y$ be an open set in $Y$.
> $(H|U)^{-1}(O) = H^{-1}(O) \cap U$.
> Since $H|U$ is continuous, $H^{-1}(O) \cap U$ is open in $U$.
> $U$ is a subspace of $X$ by assumption.
> Obviously $U$ is also a subspace of $U \cup V$.
> So, $H^{-1}(O)$ is open in $U \cup V$.

I think we don't need to assume $H|V : V \to Y$ is continuous.

Am I correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$, $U = (0, 2)$, $V = (1, 3)$ and $$
H(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} x & \textrm{if}\,\,x < 2 \\ 0 & \textrm{if}\,\, x \ge 2. \end{array}\right.
$$
Then $H$ is not continuous on $U \cup V = (0, 3)$ but is continuous on $U$. For example, if we take $O = (-1, 1)$, $H^{-1}(O) \cap U = (0, 1)$ is open in $U = (0, 2)$. It is also true that $U$ is a subspace of $U \cup V$. However, it does not guarantee that $H^{-1}(O) = (0, 1) \cup [2, 3)$ is open in $U \cup V$.

Comment: Dk-ium, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

$x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ on (0,2) and (-1,0).

Comment: Karim Mansour, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are incorrect.  It is going to be easy to construct examples where $h$ is not continuous on $V\setminus U$, and hence not continuous on $U\cup V$.

Comment: Chris Custer, Thank you very much for your answer.